# Cannot log into integrated WSL Terminal in Visual Studio Code using correct password

Tags: powershell, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Everytime i create a new WSL terminal window on Visual Studio Code for some reason I'm getting a wrong password. I know it's the correct one because I'm able to log in with no problem by using WSL itself.

These are my settings:

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
        "PowerShell": {
            "source": "PowerShell",
            "icon": "terminal-powershell"
        },
        "Command Prompt": {
            "path": [
                "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
                "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
            ],
            "args": [],
            "icon": "terminal-cmd"
        },
        "Git Bash": {
            "source": "Git Bash"
        },
        "Ubuntu (WSL)": {
            "path": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\wsl.exe",
            "args": [
                "-d",
                "Ubuntu"
            ]
        }
    },
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "PowerShell",
    "workbench.editor.empty.hint": "hidden",
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
    "terminal.integrated.shellIntegration.decorationsEnabled": "overviewRuler",
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "C:\\Users\\migue\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\python.exe",
    "terminal.integrated.env.linux": {},
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
        
        "bash": {
            "path": "bash",
            "icon": "terminal-bash"
        },
        "zsh": {
            "path": "zsh"
        },
        "fish": {
            "path": "fish"
        },
        "tmux": {
            "path": "tmux",
            "icon": "terminal-tmux"
        },
        "pwsh": {
            "path": "pwsh",
            "icon": "terminal-powershell"
        }
    }
}
```

[Screenshot for WSL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ou8U1.png)
[Screenshot for WSL integrated in Visual Studio Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxJIE.png)

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.

I tried to reproduce the way in which Visual Studio runs the WSL terminal using Powershell by running:

`./wsl -d Ubuntu`

When runnning this command in Powershell everything went fine, but using Powershell as an integrated terminal in Visual  Studio Code i get the same issue with the password.

Comment: are you running vscode with elevated privileges?

Comment: Yes, i also tried that, didn't work